# Required fields and conditionals with jQuery in Contact form 7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, forms, conditional-statements, contact-form-7

I'm coding a form on wordpress with Contact Form 7 and jQuery conditionals (thanks to [BunnyBomb](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-this-is-how-to-showhide-fields-with-jquery)). So, in a dropdown you can select the option "Individual" for showing some fields while the other fields remain hidden. Another example is that if you select in the same dropdown the option "2 Equipo (hasta 4 personas)" the other fields show up and the fields for "Invidual" and the other options remain hidden. It's up to 3 teams (12 people).

So, the problem is that these fields need to be required but I can't do that because of the hidden fields can't remain empty. Someone suggested to fill the empty fields with a "N/A" text. How can I solve these? any hints?

By the way, here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //Hide the field initially
    $("#tipo-individual").hide();
    $("#primer-equipo").hide();
    $("#segundo-equipo").hide();
    $("#tercer-equipo").hide();

    //inicio de funcion
    $('#asistencia').change(function() {
        if (($("#asistencia").val() == "Individual") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "Individuel")) {
            $("#tipo-individual").show();
            $("#primer-equipo").hide();
            $("#segundo-equipo").hide();
            $("#tercer-equipo").hide();
        } else if (($("#asistencia").val() == "1 Equipo (Hasta 4 personas)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "1 Team (4 people)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "1 équipe (4 personnes)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "1 Equipe (4)")) {
            $("#tipo-individual").hide();
            $("#primer-equipo").show();
            $("#segundo-equipo").hide();
            $("#tercer-equipo").hide();
        } else if (($("#asistencia").val() == "2 Equipo (Hasta 8 personas)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "2 Team (8 people)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "2 équipe (8 personnes)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "2 Equipe (8 pessoas)")) {
            $("#tipo-individual").hide();
            $("#primer-equipo").show();
            $("#segundo-equipo").show();
            $("#tercer-equipo").hide();
        } else if (($("#asistencia").val() == "3 Equipo (Hasta 12 personas)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "3 Team (12 people)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "3 équipe (12 personnes)") || ($("#asistencia").val() == "3 Equipe (12 pessoas)")) {
            $("#tipo-individual").hide();
            $("#primer-equipo").show();
            $("#segundo-equipo").show();
            $("#tercer-equipo").show();
        } else {
            $("#tipo-individual").hide();
            $("#primer-equipo").hide();
            $("#segundo-equipo").hide();
            $("#tercer-equipo").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All the fields which you want to hide can be set the value as NA..

```
$("#hidden_input_ID").val("NA");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It would be better if I set all the fields $("#hidden_input_ID").val("NA"); at the beginning before the function right?

Comment: Yes you can change the place of that script as suitable where it works

Comment: Can it be because it's inside of a DIV?

Comment: I found the problem. It seems that my fields didn't have an ID

Comment: Do I have to specify the field type?

Comment: Specify field type as hidden and provide them unique ids